# How to recover original data after detrending?

Tags: matlab, validation, recovery, trend

I have a vector `y` which contains the original data I have collected. I am using the MATLAB function `detrend(..)` in order to shift the data around zero and be able to compare them with another vector `x` which contains data which exist around zero. Now, what I want to do is to shift the data of vector `y` back to their original scale and also if possible shift the data of vector `x` as well in order to compare them around the area of the original data of `y`. The reason for that is because I want to compute the relative error between the data which is given by the formula:

[image]

It is obvious that `x` can't be around zero because it will cause division problems. I have tried to recover the data by adding to the detrending data the mean of the original data but it doesn;t give me back the original data. Is there any way I can do so ?

Comment: Did you somehow lose the original array?

Comment: @MadPhysicist, I had the same thought, the `y` array should still be available if needed. But the OP seems to need to know the details of the transformation because he wants to apply the inverse operation to a different vector.

Comment: I haven't lost the original array but I want to do exactly what @Hoki wrote.

Comment: How about `trend = y - detrend(y)`, and then adding `trend + x`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Detrending removes both offsets and linear trends from the data, so adding back the mean is not sufficient. You also have to add points from a line of the form `d = a*t + b`.

The two-output version of the `detrend` command returns the portion of the data, `T_r` that was removed from the original data:

```
[data_d,T_r] = detrend(___)
```

So unless you have access to `T_r` mentioned above or the equation of the line that was removed from the original data, you cannot recover it back.

You can see in MATLAB's documentation that a trend line is removed with the detrend command: https://www.mathworks.com/help/ident/ref/detrend.html

[image]